# Are better SSL certificates (better type or better encryption) better for SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, https, security-certificate, validation

I was looking at the different types of SSL certificates and providers. I came across a website that states this:

> We believe Extended and Business Verification SSL certificates gets more top rankings instead of Domain verification certs, but that is minor changes in Google algorithm

I searched Google but could not find any mention that the way a certificate is validated affects SEO (specifically with Google). I saw some websites suggest using a high key size for the certificate but I'm thinking that's for security?

**Questions:** Does Organization Validation (OV) and Extended Validation (EV) certificates get a better rank than Domain Validation (DV) certificates? What about the (RSA) key size?

Comment: The technical term for that is: "BS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of websites that provide free SSL certificates (like cloudflare, letsencrypt, google firebase and blogger.com (Only for their blogs), Wordpress.com (Only for their blogs)...)  and people using it widely. And I think Google already know about that. But they still haven't announced anything on their blog about ssl certificate choices.

In old days, domain sellers were telling people to renew their domain for 4-5 years so that google knows that you are serious about your business. They were telling people that they would get better rankings, so maybe this is also like a marketing scheme, notice their statement starts with `we believe`.

Some of these questions we won't be able to answer unless we hear official statements from google. But SSL is just one of the factors along with 200+ oher factors. Personally I advise that if your site is not an e-commerce site, then you don't need that kind of SSL, instead you can use that money to buy a better host or cloud and CDN to improve your website speed and user experience.